# Duplicates in big sets of random generated numbers

Tags: algorithm, performance, duplicates, bigdata

We need to generate random numbers on requests and those requests can be generated at anytime by any user. This leads to the problem, we have to check the previous generated numbers for any duplicates because the numbers generated should be unique and no duplicates are allowed.

Each batch of random generated numbers are around 2<sup>20</sup>-2<sup>25</sup> and the numbers generated will check every previous batch for duplicates. The numbers can't be generated in a specific interval.

As for solutions, we looked to sort the generated random numbers and then to compare with the new generated batch for duplicates, but that will take a complexity quite big O(nlogn) for a sorting algorithm.
Also at the solution of using HashSets where the memory used to store the numbers will be quite big.

Is there any way to improve the efficiency for an algorithm like this?

Comment: These are a lot of random numbers! Why not enumerate all numbers in your range and shuffle them? Then whenever a request comes in you just output the next n numbers.

Comment: http://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/ might also be worth a look

Comment: Thank you, the last link seems to help solving some of the issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use Bloom filter for two batches - current and previous. And search for duplicates in both. If found a dup (even if it is false positive) - drop it, and generate other random, until you generate unique.

What is Bloom filter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Another approach: you can use obfuscated non-random. For example - encrypt sequenced numbers with AES in ECB mode. These numbers will be seems as random, but you will be sure - encrypted numbers will not been repeated.